# Detecting a product within an image

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I want to detect a product within an image using cloud vision. If the product is too small relative to the image, then the algorithm does not  detect it.  For example, if I used an image of a product, it correctly labels it as a product but when I use a image of a person holding that product, it details plenty of (good) info about the person holding the object but fails to identify the object. Is there a way to force it?

You can use this image to test it using the Cloud Vision Web UI: https://img.bleacherreport.net/img/images/photos/003/758/947/hi-res-bc77cb085652783632d48c378e0a0ffb_crop_north.jpg?h=533&w=800&q=70&crop_x=center&crop_y=top

If I scan the entire image, it provides one label 'product' among other things. But if I crop just the coco cola in the image and scan that cropped image, it provides lot more details. E.g Coco Cola, soft drink etc. How can I get the details of the product if it only occupies a small portion within an larger image?

Comment: Did you specified the type of Google Cloud Vision API detection to perform as Martin suggested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Object Localization](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/object-localizer), which as stated can detect less prominent objects. I ran it on the image you provided, which returned 'bottle' for the cola - it also returns the boundingPoly vertices for the objects, which as you've noted you can use to crop the image and get a better detection

Comment: Perfect! Precisely the solution I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass [feature](https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/reference/rest/v1p3beta1/Feature) `PRODUCT_SEARCH` with the request, which may default to `TYPE_UNSPECIFIED` ...so that it will know, that it shall detect products and not people or other prominent objects within the view.

see [Searching for Products](https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/searching) & [Managing Products and Reference Images](https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/resource-management), which tell that, that you'd have to upload *reference images of products* to use that feature, which needs to ML learn to know these products first.

Comment: I'd like to share with you [*How to* product-search](https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/how-to) and also this link about [Managing Products and Reference Images](https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/resource-management)

Comment: I dont think the Python client that i am currently using supports this Feature. I can try calling the API directly. Let me try that and see if it works.

Comment: the PRODUCT_SEARCH type returns empty results. Here is my code:

Comment: service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('vision', 'v1p3beta1')
    with open(photo_file, 'rb') as image:
        image_content = base64.b64encode(image.read())
        service_request = service.images().annotate(body={
            'requests': [{
                'image': {
                    'content': image_content.decode('UTF-8')
                },
                'features': [ {
                    'type': 'PRODUCT_SEARCH',
                    'maxResults': 5
                }]
            }]        })
        response = service_request.execute()
        print(response)

Comment: @ArvindKandaswamy the results might be empty, while there are no reference images of products; you could use that one cropped image which get detected as such a reference image and then try to find it within a larger image (see the updated answer for details).

Comment: @MartinZeitler Appreciate the response. However, my requirement is to  search for products within an image without a reference image. If I have to give a reference image, I have to provide millions of images as I am looking to detect any product within an image. Moreover, Google already has the ML algorithm to detect a product as it could do when a cropped image is supplied and I do not need to explicitly call out. Its a bummer that it only does for the prominently displayed objects.

Comment: I was thinking if I can use crop hints to crop the image and then run the API. But interestingly enough, the API does not return boundingPoly attributes for label detection. It does for all other objects!  I guess I have to look at Tensorflow object detection API. So near yet so far!!

Comment: @ArvindKandaswamy there may be some trade off, more details = more processing power... if the first run would just detect objects and store their surrounding frame, the second would tell product & uninteresting apart, the their could then detect each single image.

Comment: @MartinZeitler When detecting the objects, the API does not return the surrounding frame. This is so unfortunate. The API returns the surrounding frame for text, face etc but not for objects.